# Fastest way to return multiple objects in Cython?

Tags: arrays, struct, cython

I am working on a Laplace.eq solver in 2D and during convergence checks the function would naturally return multiple objects. The worked-on array for starters, the number of iterations and the current estimated error.

Simplest case you can code is the jacobi method.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef void jacobi_iteration(double[:,:] A, double[:,:] mask):
    cdef int i, j, n, m
    cdef double tmp
    n, m = A.shape[0], A.shape[1]
    for i in prange(1, n-1, nogil=True):
        for j in range(1, m-1):
            if not mask[i, j]:
                tmp = 0.25 * (A[i-1, j] + A[i+1, j] + A[i, j-1] + A[i, j+1])
                A[i, j] = tmp
      

    
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef Jacobi_fx(double[:,:] A, double[:,:] mask, int max_iterations, double error):
    cdef int i, n, m, iteration
    cdef double norm, norm_prev, tmp_error
    norm_prev = 0
    norm = 0
    iteration = 0
    n, m = A.shape[0], A.shape[1]
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        norm = np.linalg.norm(A)
        jacobi_iteration(A, mask)
        tmp_error = abs(norm - norm_prev)
        norm_prev = norm
        iteration = iteration + 1
        if tmp_error < error:
            break
    return A, tmp_error, iteration
```

the 'mask' array is there for Dirichlet conditions telling the function which indexes to iterate over.

In the second function i return A, tmp_error, iteration.
When i annotate this that return statement takes the most amount of interpreting.

Now i could do

```
cpdef list Jacobi_fx(...)
```

and append the objects to a list but that is slow.

The annotation reveals that Cython per default creates a Tuple object for the return statement.

I could also do

```
cpdef double[:,::1][3] Jacobi_fx(...)
```

I am not sure if the notation is correct here. I mean as in returning a 1D array of size 3 whose elements are 2D arrays.
Unnecessary but i believe faster than working with append?

I am not sure if something like this is allowed either because i have never worked with C structs before but i saw it in a very old post on this forum while searching for an answer

```
cdef struct Data:
    double[:, :] A
    double tmp_error
    int iteration
```

and

```
cpdef Data Jacobi_fx(...):
    ...#before for loop unchanged
    data = Data(A=A, tmp_error=0.0, iteration=0)

    for i in range(max_iterations):
        norm = np.linalg.norm(data.A)
        jacobi_iteration(data.A, mask)
        data.tmp_error = abs(norm - norm_prev)
        norm_prev = norm
        data.iteration = iteration + 1
        if data.tmp_error < error:
            break
    return data
```

Or if i should use this same Method but define a Class instead? I wanted to avoid class using since the rest of the script is not very long either.

What is the most efficient way to do the multiple return statement in Cython? I know in this specific case for example the return will only happen once but in the rest of the script there are other functions which will be called multiple times for example.

Comment: You definitely can't put memoryviews in a struct. It hopefully won't compile but if it does it'll be a reference counting disaster

Comment: it did not compile it gave an error :')